# What's the difference between dict and list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand what's the difference between two examples.

```
MORSE = [".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.",
             "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."]

seen = ["".join(MORSE[ord(c) - ord('a')] for c in word)
            for word in words]
```

output: `['--...-.', '--...-.', '--...--.', '--...--.']`

and when I use the dict, it seems like use the function set().

```
{"".join(MORSE[ord(c) - ord('a')] for c in word)
            for word in words}
```

output: `{'--...-.', '--...--.'}`

Comment: You have a set at the bottom, not a dict.  There is such a thing as a set comprehension

Comment: it's behaving like a set because you are using the set comprehension syntax

Comment: Just google... http://sthurlow.com/python/lesson06/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first expression is surrounded by brackets and is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which produces a [list object](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). The second expression is surrounded by braces and is a [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), which produces a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) object containing only unique elements.

The [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) syntax can similarly be used to create a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
{x: x+1 for x in [1,2,3]}
# {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}
```

Answer (score 4):

Curly braces (`{`, `}`) are used to create both sets and dicts, depending on whether the contents are a list of single elements or a list of `key: value` pairs.

```
>>> type({"foo", "bar"})
<class 'set'>
>>> type({"foo": "bar"})
<class 'dict'>
```

Similarly, for comprehensions:

```
>>> words = ["foo", "bar"]
>>> type({word for word in words})
<class 'set'>
>>> type({word: index for index, word in enumerate(words)})
<class 'dict'>
```